# Understanding MVVM for Converting Process

Tags: c#, wpf

I am in the Process of converting a VB project to C# WPF.  We are planning to do with MVVM concept and I am in the learning process. To my understanding each form in VB is a View. Each view should have a  corresponding Model and ViewModel.
For the Second Form, another view and a corresponding Model and ViewModel. 
If there are n Forms in VB, there will be n Views, n Models and n ViewModels in C#.
 I am not sure what I asked here is right or not.  Experts here please help

Comment: Bear in mind that `WinForms` uses controls for everything, in WPF you would use DataTemplates instead. Also TextBlocks over Labels. Read up on how to use WPF. Views can also share some Models. Get comfortable with XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the view is concerned, you're right. Each form will have a view for presentation and a view model for presentation logic, or how your models should interact with the view. These are not necessarily one-to-one with models. You might have a model that encapsulates some data and business logic that you want to reuse. I suspect you VB projects had such classes.

[MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net) is a simple and effective framework you may want to look into. [This](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1037/mvvm-light-wpf-model-view-viewmodel) is a pretty good summary of MVVM using this framework.